# integrate paypal payment gateway with Select php

Tags: php, paypal

Hello everyone i have been trying to add paypal payment system in my website 
but when ever i click submit it reset the selected value and choose the first one then submit to paypal.
Here i want it to submit the correct chosen `option`. i tied few method but failed.
i hope anyone will help me to solve this problem.
i want it to submit the correct chosen option in `Select`. But it submits only first one. please modify the code and comment :)

```
<form id='paypal-info' method='post' action='#'>

    FACEBOOK_ID</br>
    <input name="fbid" value="" /></br>

    <select class="form-control" value="" name="mode" id="mode">
        <option value="gems">1300 Gems $5.00 USD</option>
        <option value="gems1">3000 Gems $10.00 USD</option>
        <option value="gems2">8000 Gems $25.00 USD</option>
        <option value="gems3">17000 Gems $50.00 USD</option>
        <option value="gems4">36000 Gems $100.00 USD</option>
        <option value="gems5">76000 Gems $200.00 USD</option>
    </select>

    <input type='submit' name='pay_now' id='pay_now' value='Pay' />
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['pay_now'])){
    $data=array(
        'merchant_email'=>'c1296562@opayq.com',
        'currency_code'=>'USD',
        'thanks_page'=>"http://mywebsite/tools/success.php",
        'notify_url'=>"http://mywebsite/tools/cancel.php",
        'cancel_url'=>"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
        'paypal_mode'=>true,
    );
    if($_POST['mode'] = gems) {
        $product_name = "1300 Gems";
        $amount = "5.00";
    }elseif($_POST['mode']=gems1){
        $product_name = "3000 Gems";
        $amount = "10.00";
    }elseif($_POST['mode']=gems2){
        $product_name = "8000 Gems";
        $amount = "25.00";
    }elseif($_POST['mode']=gems3){
        $product_name = "17000 Gems";
        $amount = "50.00";
    }elseif($_POST['mode']=gems4){
        $product_name = "36000 Gems";
        $amount = "100.00";
    }elseif($_POST['mode']=gems5){
        $product_name = "76000 Gems";
        $amount = "200.00";
    }

$fbid=$_POST['fbid'];
    echo infotutsPaypal($data,$product_name,$amount,$fbid);

}

function infotutsPaypal( $data,$product_name,$amount,$fbid) {

    define( 'SSL_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );
    define( 'SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' );

    $action = '';
    //Is this a test transaction?
    $action = ($data['paypal_mode']) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_URL;

    $form = '';

    $form .= '<form name="frm_payment_method" action="' . $action . '" method="post">';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="' . $data['merchant_email'] . '" />';
    // Instant Payment Notification & Return Page Details /
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="' . $data['notify_url'] . '" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="' . $data['cancel_url'] . '" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="' . $data['thanks_page'] . '" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />';
    // Configures Basic Checkout Fields -->
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />';
    // <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="localhost" />-->
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="' . $data['currency_code'] . '" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$product_name.'" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd"/>';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$amount.'" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="paypal" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" />';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="'.$fbid.'">';
  $form .= '<script>';
    $form .= 'setTimeout("document.frm_payment_method.submit()", 1);';
   $form .= '</script>';
    $form .= '</form>';
    return $form;
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any PHP errors? Check the top of the page's HTML, or open `error_log` in the file's directory.

Comment: nope i am not getting any error

Comment: Hmm then I guess it's because you have `=` in the if...elseif rather than `==`. Also you need to put `gems` in quotes. `if ($_POST['mode'] == "gems")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i see in the php code you make = in the if statement change it to ==, = used to set value but == used for equality